# QGIS Server doesn't render any fonts on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-server, font, ubuntugis

I just updated qgis-server package to latest 3.2.x from Ubuntugis repository (ubuntugis-unstable) and everything works fine - but font rendering. All labels on tiles, legend and print templates show up as squares:

[image]

After upgrading I got a lot of this messages in nginx error log:

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fonts - is Qt installed correctly?
```

I could fix that by adding a symbolic link from */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/fonts* to */usr/share/fonts* and updating font cache with `fc-cache -fv`. But this brought no changes to visualization of labels.

The QGIS project uses Ubuntu font installed from *ttf-ubuntu-font-family* package and shows up fine on QGIS Desktop. The font is also listed on the server using `fc-list`.

There are no error messages related to fonts neither in nginx error log nor in QGIS Server logging. Could be related to Qt so, any hints?

Comment: I think that you need to set up the environment variable,`export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=<path to font files>` for example `export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/fonts/open-sans`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, QT_QPA_FONTDIR is the key. It doesn't work exporting it as environment variable, at least when using fastcgi you have to do something like fastcgi_param QT_QPA_FONTDIR "/usr/share/fonts/open-sans"; (nginx) or SetEnv QT_QPA_FONTDIR /usr/share/fonts/open-sans (apache).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer:

You need to set up the environment variable,`export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=<path to font files>` for example export `QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/fonts/open-sans`

But when using fastcgi you have to do something like: @geraldo

**nginx**

`fastcgi_param QT_QPA_FONTDIR "/usr/share/fonts/open-sans";`

**apache**

`SetEnv QT_QPA_FONTDIR /usr/share/fonts/open-sans` .