# QGIS Server no fonts getting rendered on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: qgis-server, font

I've got my QGIS Server instance up and running and features are being rendered correctly via WMS. I can't get any labels to show up, however. I'm sure my problem is related to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288671/qgis-server-doesnt-render-any-fonts-on-ubuntu-16-04), but i'm not getting the blue boxes showing the missing fonts at all.

-I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and installed it based on [this great tutorial](https://www.igismap.com/qgis-server-installation/)

-I can't see anything in the qgis server error log because it is not getting written to. This is another thing I can't figure out but it has the same privs as the apache2 error log:
[image: error log privs]

-i've run:

```
export QT_QPA_FONTDIR=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu
```

-I've added the `SetEnv` to my apache qgis-server.conf:
[image]

-I'm pretty sure that i'm referencing the correct font on the system and in the .qgs file. `$fc-list` shows that DejaVu Sans is loaded and the style name is "Book"
[image]
And the reference in the .qgs file is:
[image]

So, i'm totally stuck. Any ideas on where to hunt next or why this font isn't working? I'm also not sure if i'm missing the QT package all together? It doesn't appear to be in aptitude.